# Web Api OData v4 not displaying controllers in Swagger UI anymore

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, odata, swagger

I had a Web Api OData v4 service working perfectly with Swagger/Swashbuckle on my machine, then a couple days later I relaunched it without changing anything and now Swagger UI does not display any of my controllers. I'm able to see the metadata info and the service appears to return data just fine.

I've tried just about everything I can think of from reinstalling packages, creating a brand new solution, and reinstalling IIS. What's weird is it stopped working in IIS & IIS Express, and I can't get any controllers to show up in a brand new solution either.

If nothing has changed in my code and nothing changed in IIS, what could have caused this? I'm at my whits-end. Any help would be appreciated!

Posting my packages in case something in there is the issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="MediaInfo.DotNetWrapper" version="1.0.7" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="MediaInfo.Native" version="17.12" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.OData" version="6.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.6" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData" version="5.7.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CSharp" version="4.4.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.8.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.8.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.DotNet.InternalAbstractions" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions" version="2.0.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel" version="2.0.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.OData.Core" version="7.4.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.OData.Edm" version="7.4.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Spatial" version="7.4.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Win32.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="NETStandard.Library" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="11.0.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Swagger" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Swashbuckle" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Swashbuckle.Core" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Swashbuckle.OData" version="3.5.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.AppContext" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Buffers" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Collections" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Concurrent" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Console" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Contracts" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Debug" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" version="4.4.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tools" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tracing" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Globalization" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Globalization.Calendars" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.IO" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.IO.Compression" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.IO.Compression.ZipFile" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.IO.FileSystem" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Linq" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Expressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Net.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Net.Sockets" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.ObjectModel" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Reflection" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Resources.ResourceManager" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Handles" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Numerics" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" version="4.3.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.8.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encodings.Web" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Text.RegularExpressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Threading" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Timer" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Xml.XDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Unity.Abstractions" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Unity.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.0.13" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Unity.Container" version="5.7.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="WebActivatorEx" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

[image]

Comment: What do you see on swagger url? Also, have you checked `Developer Tools Console` window any error(s) there?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood - I added a screenshot of what Swagger shows. It's completely empty. The only thing Chome Dev Tools Console shows is: "Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 52ms". There are also no exceptions thrown and nothing in the Output window that helps.

Comment: Did you update the NuGet Packages? I have the same issue, when I upgraded to the latest version. With Microsoft.OData 6.0 it worked. With 7.5 I have the same problem.

Comment: @schlonzo I ended up just removing Swagger from my project. It was becoming too much of a time suck and I couldn't figure it out.